# Debugging mismatch when writing and reading binary file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, read-write

I have two application, a reader and writer.

The data I'm writing and reading is members of this class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass(){}
   ~MyClass(){}
public:
   //Getters and setters are removed for simplicity
   void write(std::ofstream& ofile);
   void read(std::ifstream& file);
private:
   Aenum a= Aenum_0;

   double b= 0.0;   
   double c= 0.0;
   double d= 0.0;
   double e= 0.0;

   char charArr1[5];
   char charArr2[5];
   char charArr3[5];
   char charArr4[10];

   date_and_time time;
};
```

Where the struct and enum are:

```
struct date{
       int day = 1;
       int month = 1;
       int year = 2017;
    };
    struct hhmmss{
       int hours = 1;
       int minutes = 1;
       int seconds = 1;
    };
    struct date_and_time {
       date d;
       hhmmss t;
    };

    enum Aenum = {Aenum_0, Aenum_1, Aenum_2};
```

**The write function:**

```
void MyClass::write(std::ofstream& ofile){
   ofile.write((char*)&a, sizeof(int));                                      
   ofile.write((char*)&b, sizeof(double));                 
   ofile.write((char*)&c, sizeof(double));       
   ofile.write((char*)&d, sizeof(double));                     
   ofile.write((char*)&e, sizeof(double));                 
   ofile.write(&charArr1[0], sizeof(char)*5);   
   ofile.write(&charArr2[0], sizeof(char)*5); 
   ofile.write(&charArr3[0], sizeof(char)*5); 
   ofile.write(&charArr4[0], sizeof(char)*10);     
   ofile.write((char*)&time, sizeof(date_and_time));        
}
```

**The read function:**

```
void MyClass::read(std::ifstream& file){ 
   file.read((char*)&a, sizeof(int));   
   file.read((char*)&b, sizeof(double));                              
   file.read((char*)&d, sizeof(double));                       
   file.read((char*)&d, sizeof(double));                       
   file.read((char*)&e, sizeof(double));                              
   file.read(charArr1, sizeof(char)*5);          
   file.read(charArr2, sizeof(char)*5);             
   file.read(charArr3, sizeof(char)*5);        
   file.read(charArr4, sizeof(char)*10);
   file.read((char*)&time, sizeof(date_and_time));
}
```

Then in my writer application I do this:

```
bool writeToBinaryFile(std::vector<myClass>& myClassCollection, const std::string& outputPath){

   std::ofstream ofile;
   ofile.open(outputPath);
   if (!ofile.is_open())
      return false;

   date_and_time dtnow = getDateAndTimeNow();
   ofile.write((char*)&dtnow, sizeof(date_and_time));                    

   int numberOfmyClass = myClassCollection.size();
   ofile.write((char*)&numberOfmyClass, sizeof(int));

   for (int i = 0; i < myClassCollection.size(); i++)
      myClassCollection[i].write(ofile);

   ofile.close();
   return true;
}
```

And in the reader I do this:

```
bool loadData(const std::string& filePath){

   std::ifstream file;
   file.open(filePath);
   if (!file.is_open())   
      return false;

   date_and_time dtNow;
   int numberOfmyClass;
   file.read((char*)&dtNow, sizeof(date_and_time));
   file.read((char*)&numberOfmyClass, sizeof(int));

   for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfmyClass; i++)
   {
      MyClass myClass;
      myClass.read(file);
      //use data      
   }
   return true;
}
```

I know that the data in in class members is complete. I have another function where I write to an ASCII file, and there is no missing data.

When I read the binary file, I get correct data for the first 15 (out of 200+) members of the class. Then suddenly the values I'm reading are *garbage*, as if there are some bytes that shouldn't be there.

So what I'm asking is; am I doing something obviously wrong? And if not, what is the best way to debug such a problem?

Comment: `date_and_time` is probably a _non POD type_. That won't work for binary serialization that way.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `file.read((char*)&Aenum_0, sizeof(int));`

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `std::ios_base::binary` `open_mode`? Look at your file size.The size of the enum is not defined so use a local int var

Comment: @TheDude So does that mean, it would work *sometimes*? But unpredictable?

Comment: @MaxVollmer should be "a" there. Will edit.

Comment: And about debugging, you can put some sentinel values before and after your data and check/assert/stop if the value read do not match.

Comment: @A.A yes that's true. Changed to `std::ios_base::binary open_mode` now, thanks. (But doesn't fix the problem.)

Comment: Maybe you need a `sync()` call, if you`re on linux? Could be some buffering issue.

Comment: @A.A on windows

Comment: is `sizeof(date_and_time)` the same in both programs? I know you said you've opened the files in binary mode, but you need to check again. In text mode Windows performs line ending translation that can easily break binary file reading and writing.

Comment: @RetiredNinja  . So I first tried to set binary mode, but only on writing, didn't put it on *reading* (opening). That was the problem! Thanks guys.